# HPDPIC portability with mplab or picc compiler

Tags: embedded

Code is written in HPDPIC(By my senior classmate). Now I need to do some changes in it. But changing a parameter in HPDPIC is quite difficult (HPDPIC is quite old compiler and I didn't understand how to use it, hence thought of changing code, in another know compiler).

So before making any changes I copied the code as it is to see if it is compatible with either of my compiler(mplab or ccs picc). I did the necessary syntactical level changes but still it is showing error in object file.

Will C code on HPDPIC work (of course with some syntactical changes) on another compiler?

Comment: HPDPIC is *not* a compiler, it is merely the development environment for HiTech's C compiler.  A C compiler should be a C compiler, it is one language regardless of tool-chain - I am wondering what "syntactical" changes you had to make.  It is likley that you had different libraries and header file names, but that is nothing to do with syntax.  The simplest way to get what you need is to post a question about the diagnostic error message that is reported.  Asking "will it work" is somewhat abstract, but the answer is a qualified yes.

Comment: Agreed except for the supposition that a C compiler is a C compiler.  In practice, they all complain about different subsets of the "not really proper but I know what you want" cases, they all have their own extensions, and the means of passing through your desires to the linker, etc can be extremely different.  It's common to run into *all* of these on an embedded system.  Given memory constraints, you could even have a project that fits fine with one compiler, and exceeds the on-chip memory with another.

Comment: @Clifford : What i meant to say was...like for eg "bit name", i.e name is of type bit and hence can hold value 0 n 1 only. Then in PICC this type in not known...i have to change it to int1. So dis is d kind of syntax, and there were many more, i was talking about that i needed to change. nywaz now its working in MPLAB finally :)

Comment: @Chris:  Of course but that relates ot extensions not difference in syntax - somewhat pedantically ;-)

Comment: @mani:  Much of what you need can be achieved through a compatibility header containing definitions such as `#define bit int1`.  Most compilers have an implicit or forced include option so that the compiler inserts the header into every source during pre-processing so that you do not have to modify the code.

Comment: @Clifford - no, tolerance of syntax as well.  I had a co-worker who would habitually toss over the cube wall chunks of code developed for our PC-based test harness with struct definitions that MSVC was perfectly happy with, but which I had to clean up before gcc for our embedded product would accept.  But once I had done that, MSVC and gcc were both happy with the code.  Pragmatically, the more compilers you have successfully built something with, the more portable it is.